# Session Replication and Sticky session are not working in Clustered env using Spring Boot ,Spring HTTP session with JDBCS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat9

I want to test the Session replication in the clustered environment so I am using Spring Boot+Spring Security +Spring HTTP Session with JDBC.To enable clustered environment in local I have setup Apache HTTP server and 3 tomcat instances.

I observe that whenever user is getting logged then user session details are getting inserted into the SPRING_SESSION and SPRING_SESSION_ATTTRIBUTE tables.

But the main problem is Whenever I hit any request, every request is going to the different servers .Requests were not going to the same server.My assumption is from the same  browser if I hit the requests then all the requests must go to the same server.but this is not happening.I have enabled sticky_session in worker.properties so that all requests should go to the same server.

I want to test one more thing is if you see in homepage method(LoginController) I am getting user details whenever user is getting logged in one server, if that server goes down which are serving the requests then user details will be moved to the other server.Is below configuration suffice my requirement?

```
worker.list=balancer,status
  
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
  
worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.port=8010
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
  
worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.port=8011
worker.tomcat3.host=localhost

# status worker
worker.jkstatus.type=status
  
worker.balancer.sticky_session=true
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3
```

---

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX:1521:XXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.username=XXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXX
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
# ====================================================================================
# = Session Configuration
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
#spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=600
spring.h2.console.enabled=true



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}




@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccess;

    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccess logoutSuccess;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(" Enter >> configureGlobal() ");
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select email,password_hash,enabled from users where email=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email,r.role from users u inner join user_role ur on(u.id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(r.id=ur.role_id) where u.email=?")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        LOGGER.info(" Exit << configureGlobal() ");
    }

    /**
     * Handle Login - Authentication and Redirection
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home")
            .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/users")
            .hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(loginSuccess)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(false)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
         

    }

    
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source=new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config=new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter((CorsConfigurationSource) source);

    }
}


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" })
    public String login() {
        LOGGER.info("in login controller");
        return "login";
    }
    
     @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homepage(Model model) {
        LOGGER.info(" Enter >> homepage()********************* ");
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        LOGGER.info(" Enter >> homepage()*********************** "+name);
        User user = userManager.findUserByEmail(name);
        model.addAttribute("name", user.getFirstname());
        LOGGER.info(" Exit << homepage()************************ ");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share server.xml content in question? are you using `jvmRoute` in server.xml?

Comment: Yes I have configured

Comment: Could you please confirm the tomcat version? are you using any custom cookie for stickysession or default JSessionID?

Comment: I can see you are using `deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")`. Please confirm are you overriding default JSessionId? I can not see any suspected thing in the provided configuration file(worker.properties).

Comment: tomcat 9.No ,we are not overriding default JSESSIONID

Comment: Remove delete cookies jsessionid and test.stickysession means apache will route same session request to the same node.Request will route the any node for new sessions.